# Laravel 5, Method 'findOrFail' not found in class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm learning Laravel 5 from the Laracast course: [Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals), using PhpStorm IDE.

I have issue with the static methods of model, such as `where()`, `find()`, and `findOrFail()`.

When I use these methods PhpStorm shows:

> Method 'findOrFail' not found in class App\Article.

My model is Article, and the method `all()` works.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post the code for your Article Model, as well as the place you're trying to use the model.

Comment: how are you calling this method?

Comment: Try using [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

Answer (score 6):

Now you can use [Laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and for properly recognition of Model methods (i.e. paginate, findOrFail) add comment for your model class

> /** @mixin \Eloquent */

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for interesting. But I solved, I use query() method:

```
  public function show($id)
    {

        $article = Article::query()->findOrFail($id);

       return view('articles.show', compact('article'));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because those methods are hitting the magic method `__call` which phpStorm does not know how to follow. It's really just a shortcut for the following...

```
$article = new \App\Article;
$query = $article->newQuery();

$query->where('column', 'value')->get();
```

Comment: I'm really appreciate your answer! It's helpful for me. Thank you )

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it turned at the end that I had forgotten a single quotation mark in show.balde.php when I extended the master page:
@extends('app)
when I finally realized it and fixed it everything worked perfectly:
this worked:  $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
and this also worked:  $article = Article::query()->findOrFail($id);
I hope this helps (I tried this in Laravel 5.3).

Comment: This mistake is likely to happen to everyone because when try to extend you open brackets then press the single quote key and you assume it would add 2 single qoutes: '  ' but it doesn't do that as I tried in phpStorm IDE. That is why I thought this might be useful!